# .bind no longer working after upgrading to new Aurelia webpack plugins

Tags: aurelia

I'm trying to update my Aurelia project that uses webpack so I can `require` `.scss` files in my templates. I've looked at the [Aurelia Skeleton project for webpack](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/tree/master/skeleton-esnext-webpack/src) and have followed [this guide](https://github.com/jods4/aurelia-webpack-build/wiki) to come up with my `webpack.config` which is listed below. I have also included my `package.json` file.

I am able to load styles now, but have come across a perplexing issue. None of the my `bind` statements work anymore. The code itself didn't change and was working fine before this update attempt. I tried using `two-way`, `one-way`, etc, but that didn't work either. The `@bindable` property is always `undefined`.

```
<my-custom-element value.bind="something"></my-custom-element>
```

In `MyCustomElement`, `value` is always `undefined` although `something` is set properly.

I have tried walking back the package versions and I think it has to do with `aurelia-bootstrapper`, but I'm not sure.

I'm out of ideas on how to debug this issue. Any help would be much appreciated.

### webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const DashboardPlugin = require('webpack-dashboard/plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const { AureliaPlugin, ModuleDependenciesPlugin } = require('aurelia-webpack-plugin');
const { optimize: { CommonsChunkPlugin }, ProvidePlugin } = require('webpack')
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const project = require('./package.json');

// config helpers:
const ensureArray = (config) => config && (Array.isArray(config) ? config : [config]) || []
const when = (condition, config, negativeConfig) =>
condition ? ensureArray(config) : ensureArray(negativeConfig)

// primary config:
const title = 'Radar';
const outDir = path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist');
const srcDir = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');
const nodeModulesDir = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules');
const baseUrl = '/';

// If not done this way the plugin will try to load when only a build is required and cause it to hang.
const addDashboardPlugin = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event === 'webpack' ? [] : [new DashboardPlugin({
port: 3333
})];

const metadata = {
  port: process.env.WEBPACK_PORT || 9000,
  host: process.env.WEBPACK_HOST || 'localhost'
};

const cssRules = [
  { loader: 'css-loader' },
  {
    loader: 'postcss-loader',
    options: { plugins: () => [require('autoprefixer')({ browsers: ['last 2 versions'] })] }
  }
]

module.exports = ({ production, server, extractCss, coverage } = {}) => ({
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js'],
    modules: [srcDir, 'node_modules'],
},
entry: {
    app: ['aurelia-bootstrapper'],
    aurelia: Object.keys(project.dependencies).filter(dep => dep.startsWith('aurelia-')),
    vendor: Object.keys(project.dependencies).filter(dep => !dep.startsWith('aurelia-'))
},
devtool: production ? 'source-map' : 'inline-source-map',
output: {
    path: outDir,
    publicPath: baseUrl,
    filename: production ? '[name].[chunkhash].bundle.js' : '[name].[hash].bundle.js',
    sourceMapFilename: production ? '[name].[chunkhash].bundle.map' : '[name].[hash].bundle.map',
    chunkFilename: production ? '[name].[chunkhash].chunk.js' : '[name].[hash].chunk.js',
},
devServer: {
    contentBase: outDir,
    // serve index.html for all 404 (required for push-state)
    historyApiFallback: true,
    port: metadata.port,
    host: metadata.host,
    watchOptions: {
        aggregateTimeout: 300,
        poll: 1000
    }
},
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.scss$/i,
            issuer: [{ not: [{ test: /\.html$/i }] }],
            loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader?sourceMap', 'sass-loader?sourceMap']
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/i,
            issuer: [{ test: /\.html$/i }],
            loaders: ['css-loader?sourceMap', 'sass-loader?sourceMap']
        },
        // CSS required in JS/TS files should use the style-loader that auto-injects it into the website
        // only when the issuer is a .js/.ts file, so the loaders are not applied inside html templates
        {
            test: /\.css$/i,
            issuer: [{ not: [{ test: /\.html$/i }] }],
            use: extractCss ? ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                fallback: 'style-loader',
                use: cssRules,
            }) : ['style-loader', ...cssRules],
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/i,
            issuer: [{ test: /\.html$/i }],
            // CSS required in templates cannot be extracted safely
            // because Aurelia would try to require it again in runtime
            use: cssRules,
        },
        { test: /\.html$/i, loader: 'html-loader' },
        {
            test: /\.js$/i, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: nodeModulesDir,
            options: coverage ? { sourceMap: 'inline', plugins: ['istanbul'] } : {},
        },
        { test: /\.json$/i, loader: 'json-loader' },
        // use Bluebird as the global Promise implementation:
        { test: /[\/\\]node_modules[\/\\]bluebird[\/\\].+\.js$/, loader: 'expose-loader?Promise' },
        // embed small images and fonts as Data Urls and larger ones as files:
        { test: /\.(png|gif|jpg|cur)$/i, loader: 'url-loader', options: { limit: 8192 } },
        { test: /\.woff2(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/i, loader: 'url-loader', options: { limit: 10000, mimetype: 'application/font-woff2' } },
        { test: /\.woff(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/i, loader: 'url-loader', options: { limit: 10000, mimetype: 'application/font-woff' } },
        // load these fonts normally, as files:
        { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|otf)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/i, loader: 'file-loader' },
    ]
},
plugins: [
    new AureliaPlugin(),
    new ModuleDependenciesPlugin({
        'aurelia-dialog': ['./ai-dialog', './ai-dialog-header', './ai-dialog-footer', './ai-dialog-body',
            './attach-focus', './dialog-configuration', './dialog-controller', './dialog-options', './dialog-renderer',
            './dialog-result', './dialog-service', './lifecycle', './renderer'],
        'aurelia-chart': ['./elements/chart-element', './attributes/chart-attribute', './observers/model-observer']
    }),
    new ProvidePlugin({
        'Promise': 'bluebird'
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: 'index.ejs',
        minify: production ? {
            removeComments: true,
            collapseWhitespace: true
        } : undefined,
        metadata: {
            title, server, baseUrl
        },
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        { from: 'src/config', to: 'config' },
        { from: 'styles/img', to: 'img' }
    ]),
    ...when(extractCss, new ExtractTextPlugin({
        filename: production ? '[contenthash].css' : '[id].css',
        allChunks: true,
    })),
    ...when(production, new CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'common'
    })),
    new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin({
        assetNameRegExp: /\.scss$/i,
        cssProcessor: require('cssnano'),
        cssProcessorOptions: { discardComments: { removeAll: true } },
        canPrint: true
    })
].concat(addDashboardPlugin)
})
```

### package.json

```
"dependencies": {
  "aurelia-animator-css": "^1.0.0",
  "aurelia-application-insights": "^1.0.0",
  "aurelia-binding": "^1.2.0",
  "aurelia-bootstrapper": "^2.1.1",
  "aurelia-chart": "^0.2.6",
  "aurelia-configuration": "1.0.17",
  "aurelia-dependency-injection": "^1.3.1",
  "aurelia-dialog": "^1.0.0-beta.3.0.0",
  "aurelia-event-aggregator": "^1.0.1",
  "aurelia-fetch-client": "^1.1.2",
  "aurelia-framework": "^1.1.0",
  "aurelia-history": "^1.0.0",
  "aurelia-history-browser": "^1.0.0",
  "aurelia-logging": "^1.3.1",
  "aurelia-logging-console": "^1.0.0",
  "aurelia-metadata": "^1.0.3",
  "aurelia-notify": "^0.8.1",
  "aurelia-pal": "^1.3.0",
  "aurelia-pal-browser": "^1.1.0",
  "aurelia-path": "^1.0.0",
  "aurelia-route-recognizer": "^1.0.0",
  "aurelia-router": "^1.3.0",
  "aurelia-task-queue": "^1.2.0",
  "aurelia-templating": "^1.3.0",
  "aurelia-templating-binding": "^1.3.0",
  "aurelia-templating-resources": "^1.3.1",
  "aurelia-templating-router": "^1.1.0",
  "aurelia-validation": "^1.0.0",
  "bluebird": "^3.3.5",
  "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
  ... //omitted for clarity
},
"devDependencies": {
  "aurelia-loader-nodejs": "^1.0.1",
  "aurelia-pal-nodejs": "^1.0.0-beta.1.0.0",
  "aurelia-tools": "^1.0.0",
  "aurelia-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-rc.2",
  "autoprefixer": "^7.0.0",
  "babel-core": "^6.17.0",
  "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
  "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
  "babel-plugin-istanbul": "^4.1.3",
  "babel-plugin-lodash": "^3.2.10",
  "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
  "babel-plugin-transform-decorators": "^6.24.1",
  "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
  "babel-polyfill": "^6.16.0",
  "babel-preset-env": "^1.5.1",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
  "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.24.1",
  "babel-register": "^6.11.6",
  "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
  "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
  "cross-env": "^3.1.3",
  "css-loader": "^0.28.1",
  "eslint": "^3.12.2",
  "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
  "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
  "html-server": "^0.1.1",
  "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.22.0",
  "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
  "node-sass": "^3.13.0",
  "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^1.3.2",
  "package": "^1.0.1",
  "postcss-loader": "^1.3.3",
  "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
  "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
  "sass-loader": "^4.0.2",
  "style-loader": "^0.17.0",
  "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
  "webpack": "^2.6.1",
  "webpack-dashboard": "^0.2.0",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5"
}
```

### nav-bar.html

```
<template>
<require from='./_nav-bar.scss'></require>

<section class="nav-bar nav-bar__group" data-grid="full">
        <div data-grid="full">
            <main-menu router.bind="router" data-grid="21"></main-menu>
            <user-panel data-grid="3"></user-panel>
        </div>
</section>
</template>
```

### main-menu.html

```
<template class="main-menu">
<ul class="main-menu__nav-list">
    <li repeat.for="row of router.navigation">
        <a href.bind="row.href"
            data-appinsights-category="navigation"
            data-appinsights-action="${row.title}"
            data-text="${row.title}">
                ${row.title}
            </a>
    </li>
</ul>
</template>
```

### main-menu.js

```
import { bindable, inject } from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(Element)
export class MainMenuCustomElement {
  //This value is always undefined now
  @bindable router;

  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;
  }

  toggleMenu() {
    //removed for brevity
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any error messages in the console? Could you show the custom-element's code?

Comment: No error messages are in the console. I added the code from one of the custom element's, but this issue is happening across the board. Also, this code worked before the upgrade.

Comment: It's difficult to figure out what is happening without seeing the real code. Your code seems fine. I would try to find something wrong in your app.js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work after adding `import babel-polyfill` to `main.js`, changing `.babelrc` to reference `.babelrc.js like so:

```
{
  "presets": [ "./.babelrc.js" ] 
}
```

I also included `.babelrc.js` from the skeleton-navigation project.

### .babelrc.js

```
// this file will be used by default by babel@7 once it is released
module.exports = {
  "plugins": [
    "transform-decorators-legacy",
    "transform-class-properties"
  ],
  "presets": [
    [
      "env", {
        "targets": process.env.BABEL_TARGET === 'node' ? {
          "node": process.env.IN_PROTRACTOR ? '6' : 'current'
        } : {
          "browsers": [
            "last 2 versions",
            "not ie <= 11"
          ],
          "uglify": process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
        },
        "loose": true,
        "modules": process.env.BABEL_TARGET === 'node' ? 'commonjs' : false,
        "useBuiltIns": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```